# A small backup script in Python

Tags: python, python-2.x

I work on ubuntu machine and my backup requirements are straightforward. My only requirement is the usual copy paste, but only changed files (ie. the files whose modification-time OR size has changed) should get replaced.

Since I could not find such option in the default nautilus copy-paste (it only allows a merge with a blanket replace), I decided to write a backup script in python myself that I would like to get reviewed. Here is the script for backup.py:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python
#@module: backup.py
#@description: Script to take backup to a fixed location
#@author: Prahlad Yeri
#@copyright: MIT Licensed

#from __future__ import print_function
import os
import os.path
import sys
import time
from datetime import datetime
import shutil

backup_loc = '/media/username/1tera/backup'
#backup_loc = '/tmp/backup'

locations = ['/home/username/docs',
    '/home/username/source',
    '/home/username/scripts',
    '/home/username/library',
    '/home/username/programs',
    '/home/username/staging',
    '/home/username/soft',
    '/home/username/Desktop',
    '/home/username/Downloads',
    '/home/username/movies',
    '/home/username/songs',
    ]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    #loop thru the folders
    start = time.clock()
    num=0
    for s in locations: #[0:1]:
        #print s + "\n"
        #files = os.listdir(s)
        print 'listing for '  + s
        for (root, dirs, files) in os.walk(s):
            subpath = root.replace('/home/prahlad','')
            for f in files:
                filename = os.path.join(root, f)
                dfilename = backup_loc + subpath + os.sep + f
                link = ''
                if os.path.islink(filename):
                    link = os.readlink(filename)


                if not os.path.exists(dfilename):
                    #check dirs
                    if not os.path.exists(backup_loc + subpath):
                        os.makedirs(backup_loc + subpath)
                        print 'creating directory: ' + backup_loc + subpath

                    #just copy the files
                    print 'copying from: ' + filename
                    print 'to: ' + dfilename
                    if link == '':
                        shutil.copy2(filename, dfilename)
                    else:
                        os.symlink(link, dfilename)
                    num+=1
                else:
                    sz = os.path.getsize(filename); lm = datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(filename)).timetuple()
                    dsz = os.path.getsize(dfilename); dlm = datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(dfilename)).timetuple()

                    if (sz == dsz and lm == dlm):
                        print 'skipped: ' + dfilename
                        #time.sleep(3)
                    else:
                        #copy the files
                        print 'copying from: ' + filename
                        print 'to: ' + dfilename
                        if link == '':
                            shutil.copy2(filename, dfilename)
                        else:
                            os.symlink(link, dfilename)
                        num+=1

    mins = (time.clock() - start)
    #print "All files copied in %d minutes" % mins
    print "{0} files copied in {1} minutes".format(int(num), round(mins))
```

Comment: Why not just use [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync)? It automatically doesn't copy files that are the same at the destination.

Comment: @whereswalden - As I've mentioned I want a more customized solution. For instance, a recent requirement I've thought of is that I'm into habit of renaming my folders for aesthetics (eg: apache-mysql to lamp, etc.). In those cases, I want the old folder in corresponding backup to be deleted first, otherwise, it would be a disk-wastage and disorganization. Can rsync do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't think of any way the file size could change without the mtime
changing too. On the other hand, it does no harm to check, aside from
making the code a little more complex.

You use the expression `backup_loc + subpath` quite often, so I would do
this:

```
subpath = root.replace('/home/prahlad/','')   # note extra slash
backup_path = os.path.join(backup_loc, subpath)
...
dfilename = os.path.join(backup_path, f)
...
if not os.path.exists(backup_path):
    os.makedirs(backup_path)
    print 'creating directory: ' + backup_path
```

For these lines, I would do one thing per line, and move the complex
expression into a function:

```
sz = os.path.getsize(filename); lm = datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(filename)).timetuple()
dsz = os.path.getsize(dfilename); dlm = datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(dfilename)).timetuple()
```

As follows:

```
def file_mtime(path):
    return datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(path)).timetuple()
...
sz = os.path.getsize(filename)
lm = file_mtime(filename)
dsz = os.path.getsize(dfilename);
dlm = file_mtime(dfilename)
```

However, since you're only comparing one timestamp to another, and not
doing anything else with the timestamps, I don't see why you couldn't
just do this:

```
lm = os.path.getmtime(filename)
...
dlm = os.path.getmtime(dfilename)
```

`time.clock()` returns time in seconds, not minutes; and `num` is
already an `int`; so:

```
mins = round((time.clock() - start) / 60)
print "{0} files copied in {1} minutes".format(num, int(mins))
```

Comment: Thanks. I liked your suggestions regarding backup_loc + subpath. I'm accepting this answer.